# How to copy corresponding row header and column header if a cell contains a number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I extracted messy, raw data that need to be in a table format.
[image: raw data]

This is my goal:
[image: goal]

The code produces this outcome:
[image: outcome]

```
Sub sample()

Dim rnge As Range, erow As Long

lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value) = True Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Copy            
        erow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row            
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 1)

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy            
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 3)

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Copy            
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 2)                        
    End If        
Next i

End Sub
```

Based on the outcome, is there any way to remove those data that don't have numeric values? As soon as column B is done, is it possible for the for loop function to move into column C without writing specific code over again?

Comment: Does this need to be done in vba?

Comment: @Warcupine It doesn’t have to be. If you have suggestions, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will get you your desired results, see notes in the code for explanation.

```
Option Explicit


Sub sample()

Dim i As Long, pRow As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Col As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet, ResSht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' <-- rename worksheet to fit your need
Set ResSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results") ' <-- rename worksheet to fit your need

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column (Header row of Animals)

    ' add header row in "Results"
    ResSht.Range("A1").Value = "Colors"
    ResSht.Range("B1").Value = "Animals"
    ResSht.Range("C1").Value = "Value"
    pRow = 2

    For i = 2 To LastRow ' loop through rows
        ' loop through columns
        For Col = 2 To LastCol
            ' check if there's a numeric value in cell (and not empty)
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, Col).Value) And Trim(.Cells(i, Col).Value) <> "" Then
                ' add new row to "Results"
                ResSht.Range("A" & pRow).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value ' get the color from column A
                ResSht.Range("B" & pRow).Value = .Cells(1, Col).Value ' get the Animal from the header row
                ResSht.Range("C" & pRow).Value = .Cells(i, Col).Value ' get the Value from the cell

                pRow = pRow + 1
            End If
        Next Col
    Next i

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```