# Using a checkboxes to create a data set to be copied in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a sheet to optimise task completion. I've got four work sheets in total.

I'm aware excel has a "scenario" function, I am not referring to this when I mention it below.

1. "Input" - a simple checkbox table the user can select which tasks will be completed in "Scenario". When a button is pressed the scenario is saved as "Scenario 1" and the completion score is calculated and put into the sheet named "Output"

[image]

2. "Table" - Backend matrix that I'm using the calculate the completion score to copy over to each scenario. I'm comfortable with the code needed to copy the updated completion score to the sheet named "Calc Sheet".

[image]

3. "Calc Sheet" - Backend calculation table, that will have the "Value to copy" pasted/overwritten  in the "Scenario Uplift" Column. The total score for the aspect is calculated here and then copied to a running total.

[image]

4. "Output" - a dashboard that ideally shows the components of each saved "scenario" as well as a graph tracking the increasing completion score.

[image]

Where I am stuck is on the following:

-Pulling through the selected options/checkboxes that each scenario comprises of to the "Output Sheet". I was trying to build out another row and column to the matrix on "Table" to turn true if there was any true within the row/column, and copy the corresponding row/column title, but this solution wouldn't hold when calculating the running total. I feel like there is some super obvious solution using the array position of the "true" but I'm being dense. :(

-Once a ticked check box has been included in a scenario, is there a way to "freeze" it so it cannot be selected again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I absolutely over complicated this. Found the code I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382505/how-to-copy-corresponding-row-header-and-column-header-if-a-cell-contains-a-numb 
Just instead of a number, it looks for if it contains "True". Now working on how to the results into the next blank column as opposed to over writing. But thats a challenge I want to do on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

Hugely overcomplicated this.

I needed to obtain the row and column headers if a value in the "Table" sheet was true. Using this code but modifying it to instead of look at numbers, just simply the word "True".
[How to copy corresponding row header and column header if a cell contains a number in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382505/how-to-copy-corresponding-row-header-and-column-header-if-a-cell-contains-a-numb)

```
    Sub ColumnandRow()

Dim i As Long, pRow As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Col As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet, ResSht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")
Set ResSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column (Header row of Animals)

    ' add header row in "Results"
    ResSht.Range("A1").Value = "Reference"
    ResSht.Range("B1").Value = "Type"
   
    pRow = 2

    For i = 2 To LastRow ' loop through rows
        ' loop through columns
        For Col = 2 To LastCol
            
            If InStr(1, (.Cells(i, Col).Value), "True") > 0 Then
                
                
                ' add new row to "Results"
                ResSht.Range("A" & pRow).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                ResSht.Range("B" & pRow).Value = .Cells(1, Col).Value
                
                pRow = pRow + 1
            End If
        Next Col
    Next i

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```